# Is using a Timestamp still an effective method to stop spam registrations?

Tags: sql-server, spam-prevention

The type of form in question would be a user registration form, with autocomplete disabled on the fields, although I'm aware that browsers are ignoring this for password fields.

I've used honey pot for a long time, but curious if anyone has had success *recently* with using a time-stamp. I see lots of posts mentioning it, but curious if bots have caught up, as in putting timers or delays on their methods.

For example, in SQL Server:

```
Create Procedure dbo.Registration
   @StartTime datetime

AS BEGIN

declare @TimeSpent int = datediff(second, @StartTime, getdate())

IF @TimeSpent < 5
BEGIN
  throw error or deny registration
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  looks good...
END
```

END

Comment: @aphrael Sure did. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Why not use captchas?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I try to do everything possible to eliminate any burden on the end user. I highly dislike captchas.

Comment: This seems like it will work for some bots but not all. Captcha is sort of the universally accepted headache with websites currently. Another option would be to use a software keyboard to enter the email address and have it send a validation link. If you do the software keyboard you just need to be deceptive in your naming so the bots can't easily decipher it.